AlignmentMarker in GridBox inconsistently inserts unwanted indention in the displayed column
"14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"
The screen capture shows the same column of expressions with the exception that the second version has a logical and symbol preceding the first \[AlignmentMarker].

The following is a cell copy of the first cell:

\[AlignmentMarker]\[ScriptF][\[Alpha]]=Min[\[ScriptF][\[ScriptCapitalD]]]
\[And]\[AlignmentMarker]\[ScriptF][\[Beta]]=Max[\[ScriptF][\[ScriptCapitalD]]]
\[InvisibleComma]\[And]\[AlignmentMarker]\[ScriptF][\[Alpha]] <=\[ScriptF] 
[\[ScriptCapitalD]]<=\[ScriptF][\[Beta]
\[And]\[AlignmentMarker]\[ScriptCapitalR]\[Congruent][\[ScriptF][\[Alpha]],\[ScriptF]
[\[Beta]]]

This is but one example of how GridBoxAligmnet inserts unwanted indentation into the display of mathematical expressions.  I encountered this problem in version 13 and reported it as a bug. The indentation changes as soon as I type 'Escan'.  Once the entire 'EscandEsc' is input, the second cell is produced.  If I then delete the \[And], the indentation remains until the formatting is refreshed.  For example by hitting 'Ctrl+Shift+Esc'.  This behavior is not consistent.  Sometimes I can insert an invisible comma Esc,Esc to fix the indentation.
Are others able to reproduce this behavior?  If so, on what platforms and versions?
This is how to create such content from scratch. A column is created in a Display Formula styled cell using 'Ctrl+Enter'.  Then 'Ctrl+Shift+E' reveals:

Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[GridBox[{
    {"\[Placeholder]"},
    {"\[Placeholder]"}
   }], TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->
  TraditionalForm]], "DisplayFormula"]

After the closing '}' in the GridBox enter:

,ColumnAlignments->"\\[AlignmentMarker]"

That is:

Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[GridBox[{
    {"\[Placeholder]"},
    {"\[Placeholder]"}
   },ColumnAlignments->"\[AlignmentMarker]"
   ], TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->
  TraditionalForm]], "DisplayFormula"]

Then 'Ctrl+Shift+E' to get back to edit mode and populate the placeholders with expressions with, for example:
.
[ForAll][Alpha] [Exists][a=b+c+d]
[Therefore]x=y
.
Now 'Ctrl+Shift+E' shows:
.
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
FormBox[GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"[ForAll]",
RowBox[{"[Alpha]",
RowBox[{"[Exists]",
RowBox[{"[",
RowBox[{"a", "=",
RowBox[{"b", "+", "c", "+", "d"}]}],
"]"}]}]}]}]},
{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"[Therefore]", "x"}], "=", "y"}]}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
"Columns" -> {{"[AlignmentMarker]"}},
"Rows" -> {{Baseline}}}],
TraditionalForm]]]], "DisplayFormula"]
.
Note that ColumnAlignments has been converted into GridBoxAlignments.
Use 'Ctrl+Shift+E' to return to edit mode. Insert (invisible) AlignemntMarker symbols using 'EscamEsc' as the second character in each row.

\[ForAll]\[AlignmentMarker]\[Alpha] \[Exists][a=b+c+d]
\[Therefore]\[AlignmentMarker]x=y

The rows are not indented:

Delete the first (\[ForAll]) character of the first row so that the \[AlignmentMarker] become the first character.  The rows are now indented:

Unfortunately the behavior is different in version 14 than it was in version 13, but still not what should be expected.  I have about 100 notebooks, several of which are extensive.  I fixed them once, but now they are broken again.  For example:

